# Активный раздел в меню

Tags: jquery

Как можно на jQuery сделать, чтобы по переходу по ссылке к ней добавлялся класс active, а с предыдущей убирался? Чтобы в меню видеть, какой раздел сейчас открыт

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
(function(){
 $('#menu li a').click(function () {
        $('#menu li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        return true;
    });
}) ();
```

```css
#menu li.active a{
 color: #FFC002;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="menu">
 <li class="active"><a href="#">Пункт</a>
 <li><a href="#">Пункт</a>
    <li><a href="#">Пункт</a>    
    <li><a href="#">Пункт</a>   
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вообще добавление и удаление классов CSS в jQuery осуществляется
с помощью методов addClass() и removeClass().

Например:

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $("#div1").addClass("important blue");
});
$("button").click(function(){
    $("h1, h2, p").removeClass("blue");
});
```

Однако в вашем случае, возможно, jQuery вообще не понадобится,
потому что *при переходе по ссылке* вы (предположительно) загружаете новую страницу в текущее окно браузера, что делает манипуляции с элементами старой бессмысленными.

Если же у вас это не переход по ссылке, а просто смена состояния страницы,
то используйте `addClass` и `removeClass` как в моём примере выше.

Подробнее о addClass и removeClass:

- https://api.jquery.com/addClass/ (англ.)
- https://api.jquery.com/removeClass/ (англ.)

Answer (score 0):

Через кукисы допустимо?
При клике на пункт меню в переменную записывается ее номер, при загрузки страницы проверяется переменная и нужному элементу присваивается класс active.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение,